# How to implement long running proceses in Jakarta EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

In my Jakarta EE app, I have a process that is importing CSV data from the filesystem on a scheduled base.
For that reason I have implemented this service with a timerService to be able to configure the scheduling based on a cron expression.

```java
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ImportService {
    @Resource
    javax.ejb.TimerService timerService;

    public void start() {
        Timer timer = null;
        timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(scheduerExpression, id);
        ...
    }

    @Timeout
    protected void onTimeout(javax.ejb.Timer timer) {
      ....
      // call Stateless EJBs...
    }
}
```

Of course the `onTimeout` method is running in a new container managed transaction. If my import process takes a lot of time (more the 5 minutes) eventually I run into a TransactionTimeout and my process is canceled and rolled back.

I can increase the transaction timeout in my application Server (Wildfly) from 5 min to e.g. 60 min.

But I wonder what is the best way to implement such long running jobs in Jakarta EE to avoid long running transactions?

Comment: I think JEE Batch Processing (JSR 352) would be the right tool for this job. You will probably have to implement a way of reading the CSV line-by-line or in batches and keep the offset for the next read in the batch persistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to execute an action on a reoccurring `@Timeout` (eg. every 5/10mins) that works on the files for a limited amount of time (eg. 1min) to ensure you don't hit any transaction timeouts.

You could copy the .CSV file on first load and truncate it on each timeout to remove the lines that have already been processed